# Is it possible to execute the remaining code if pdo exception is occurred?

Tags: php, pdo, error-handling

I have a config.php file which is as following:

```
//file name: config.php -------------
define ("DOMAIN","mydomain.com");
//connection parameters
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$db   = 'test';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$charset = 'utf8mb4';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
    echo "Database connected successfully!";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    throw new PDOException($e->getMessage());
}
```

and now I have including this file in the index.php as follows:

```
//file name: index.php -----------
require_once("../path to/config.php");
echo "WELCOME to <h1 style='display:inline;color:#000080;'>".DOMAIN."</h1>";
```

As you can see, the credentials are fake, it will not be able to connect to the database, so the error message is showing as below:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/hosting_account/path to/config.php:20 Stack trace: #0 /home/hosting_account/public_html/index.php(22): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in /home/hosting_account/path to/config.php on line 20
```

I have removed the actual path here but mentioned the layout of the path. All works normal.. The error message is normal as well.

But what I want, the first line of the index.php will be executing/showing (Welcome to mydomain.com) even there will be an error in a part of (here the connection part) the included file. As there is no error in defining the DOMAIN and echoing it from the index.php, I want it will show the "Welcome to mydomain.com" and then will show the error message caught from the pdo connection.

How to do that?

Comment: If you replace `throw new PDOException($e->getMessage());` on some other, for example `$pdo_error = 1; $message = $pdo->getMessage()` than you can throw it after welcome message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 //file name: config.php -------------
 define ("DOMAIN","mydomain.com");
 //connection parameters
 $host = '127.0.0.1';
 $db   = 'test';
 $user = 'root';
 $pass = '';
 $charset = 'utf8mb4';

 $pdo_error = 0;
 $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
 $options = [
     PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT,
     PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
     PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
 ];
 try {
     $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
     echo "Database connected successfully!";
 } catch (PDOException $e) {
     //throw new PDOException($e->getMessage());
     $pdo_error = 1;
     $error_message = $e->getMessage();
 }
```

And then

```
//file name: index.php -----------
require_once("../path to/config.php");
echo "WELCOME to <h1 style='display:inline;color:#000080;'>".DOMAIN."</h1>";
if($pdo_error){
    throw new PDOException($error_message);
}
```

Comment: Thankyou.... I have understood it well and it works! But the error message is not showing if the php_value display_errors 0 is set in the .htaccess file. But if I use just echo $error_message, only SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) is showing for both 0 or 1 for the php_value display_error. Would you please explain the function of throw here?

Comment: It happens because display_errors 0 canceled all error output. But if your server has a error log, it output will be written to this log. But echo isn`t error output. And echo displayed always even display_errors is 0

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't display any errors on the production server - you should log it instead. If you are not using any framework you can simply save it to the file instead of displaying it - do all of it in the `catch` block.

Besides you are catching and throwing the same exception one more time.

```php
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    throw new PDOException($e->getMessage());
}
```

please edit this part as you with to handle it.